# How to save jwt token in cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

How do i save this jwt token in my cookies

After so many trials i can't see it in my cookies

i don't know where the error is from

beside i got no errors or warning

These is my **authController** code

```
const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              id: userCreate._id,
              email: userCreate.email,
              userName: userCreate.userName,
              image: userCreate.image,
              registerTime: userCreate.createdAt,
            },
            process.env.SECRET,
            {
              expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXP,
            }
          );
          const options = {
            expires: new Date(
              Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXP * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            ),
          };
          res.status(201).cookie("authToken", token, options).json({
            successMessage: "Your Registration is successful",
            token,
          });
        } else {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: {
              errorMessage: ["Internal server error"],
            },
          });
        }
```

then this is my **server.js**

here i'm passing both bodyParser and cookieParser

```
 const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const { handleNotFound } = require("./utils/helper");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middlewares/error");
dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the  credentials:include property in your frontend fetch method which is used to interact with this route . Or if you're using axios set property withCredentials
to true